# Using Wildcards in Index(Match) function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, wildcard

I am using an `Index(Match())` function in my vba code that seems to be experiencing some issues.  Because some of the searched criterion aren't exactly alike, I am trying to use a `"*"` wildcard operator around cell `C2` to search for like items.  Also, I do not want to simply place the formula I am using into cells with a `Range("D2").Formula` code that will cause auto-updating, therefore, I am experiencing issues around this as well.

Here is my code.

`Range("D2") = Index('Future_220_140_MON'!$B$20:$AK$24, Match(" * "&C2&" * "&T2, 'Future_220_140_MON'!$B$1:$AK$1&'Future_220_140_MON'!$A$20:$A$24, 0))`

Am I simply misformatting the code, or is there a particular way to call out wildcards when matching multiple criterion.

Comment: What error are you getting?  A debug error?  An invalid result?

Comment: Is there any reason why you've offset your wildcard with spaces? Should work if you do `Match("*"&C2&"*"&T2, ...`

Comment: You're also mixing VBA functions with Worksheet functions, which probably would explain any errors you may be getting.

Comment: @Chrismas007 I am getting a `Expected: Expression` error when I run the code as shown above.  If I switch to the `Range("D2").Formula = "=Index('Future_220_140_MON'!$B$20:$AK$24, Match(" * "&C2&" * "&T2, 'Future_220_140_MON'!$B$1:$AK$1&'Future_220_140_MON'!$A$20:$A$24, 0))"` then I get a type mismatch

Comment: @ksmit144 You were getting the expression error because of the `"` at the end of the line which I see you have edited out now.  I have also edited that errant quote out of my solution.

Comment: Actually I removed the `"` because I mistakenly placed that in my question without using it during my coding.  My code above still results in an `Expected: Expression`

Comment: Your `MATCH` function will always return #N/A error because the lookup array isn't a single row or column - you are concatenating a horizontal range (36 columns) with a vertical one (5 rows) which will give you a 36x5 matrix - if that's intentional then you will need to find a different way

Comment: I supect you need to use **two** MATCH functions like this: = `=Index('Future_220_140_MON'!$B$20:$AK$24, Match("*"&C2&"*",'Future_220_140_MON'!$A$20:$A$24, 0),MATCH("*"&T2&"*",'Future_220_140_MON'!$B$1:$AK$1,0))` - one MATCH gives you the row, the next MATCH gives the column and then INDEX returns the value at the intersection

Comment: @barry houdini Ah that makes sense.  I have used concatenation before to solve an `index(match())` function, but I guess the circumstances are slightly different.  Let me check if this solves my problem.

Comment: Yes, you might use concatenation in some circumstances (e.g. 2 criteria in two different columns) but when you have to match a row and a column you need two MATCH functions, in the order shown

Comment: @barryhoudini So `Range("D2") = Index('Future_220_140_MON'!$B$20:$AK$24, Match(" * "&C2&" * ",'Future_220_140_MON'!$A$20:$A$24, 0),MATCH($T2,'Future_220_140_MON'!$B$1:$AK$1,0))` is still resulting in a syntax error.  Is that because I need to reformat the code as an `application.worksheetfunction`?

Comment: That's one for Rory!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Range("D2").Value = Application.Index(Sheets("Future_220_140_MON").Range("B20:AK24"), _
Application.Match(Range("T2").Value, Sheets("Future_220_140_MON").Range("A20:A24"),0), _
Application.Match("*" & Range("C2").Value & "*", Sheets("Future_220_140_MON").Range("B1:AK1"),0))
```

Based on clarification, the code would need to be like this:

```
    Range("D2").Value = Application.Index(Sheets("Future_220_140_MON").Range("B20:AK24"), _
Application.Match(Range("T2").Value, Sheets("Future_220_140_MON").Range("A20:A24"),0), _
Application.Match(Mid$(Range("C2").Value, Instr(Range("C2").Value, "_") + 1), Sheets("Future_220_140_MON").Range("B1:AK1"),0))
```

Further edit: if you want to actually put a formula in place:

```
Range("D2").Formula = "=Index('Future_220_140_MON'!$B$20:$AK$24,Match(T2,'Future_220_140_MON'!$A$20:$A$24,0),Match(MID(C2,FIND(""_"",C2)+1,LEN(C2)),'Future_220_140_MON'!$B$1:$AK$1,0))
```

Comment: The value in `C2` that I am trying to match to `B1:AK1` does not want to acknowledge the similarities.  The value of `C2` has a number before it, such as `1_Unpack` and I am trying to match that to the value in `B1:AK1` that says `Unpack`.  Because it does not see the match, the cell in `D1` reads `#N/A`

Comment: You can't add wildcards to C2 for that. Is it always a number followed by underscore?

Comment: Yes, it is always a number from 1-35 followed by an underscore.

Comment: The equation works great thanks! However, I tried to implement it with an `autofill` from `D2` to `D3150` and it doesn't seem to want to move `C2` to `C3` or `T2` to `T3` etc.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should always define what you want your result to be stored as.  By default, just writing `Range("D2")` will use the `.Value` property of the cell, but it is better to write `Range("D2").Value`.  Also both of your functions are actually `Application.WorksheetFunction`s.  Try this code:

```
Dim MatchResult As Double
MatchResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Conditions)
Range("D2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Conditions, MatchResult)
```

[`WorksheetFunction.Index` Method MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197581%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[`WorksheetFunction.Match` Method MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: I am not entirely sure why the code outputs a Syntax Error but both lines of code in my worksheet are faulty.  `MatchResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("*"&C2&"*"&T2, 'Future_220_140_MON'!$B$1:$AK$1&'Future_220_140_MON'!$A$20:$A$24, 0)` and `Range("D2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index('Future_220_140_MON'!$B$20:$AK$24, MatchResult)` result in errors.

Comment: The error results from `"*"&C2&"*"`.  It highlights that portion and states `Expected: List separator or )`

Comment: You can't use strings instead of ranges for `AWF.Index` or `AWF.Match` and you can't concatenate ranges like that either. You'd need `Evaluate` with a formula string. However that original formula looks wrong to me anyway.

Comment: @Rory So concatenating the search criteria when using a wildcard is an understandable error, but is there a way to search for multiple criterion in another way?

Comment: @ksmit144 What does your data look like? It appears to me at first glance as though you actually need an `INDEX(...,match(), match())` syntax - i.e. looking one value up in the first column and one in the top row to return a cell from a table.

Comment: See my comment on your question - you can only use MATCH with a single row or column, so it's the way you are using MATCH that is the problem, not an issue with any VBA issue - you need two MATCH functions, see above - Hey rory! Snap!

Comment: @Rory Basically, I am trying to match `T2` to the correct value in Column `$A$20:$A$24` to get a row value, while matching `C2` to a similar value in Row `$B$1:$AK$1` to get a column value.  Then the index gives me the value from the Range `$B$20:$AK$24` to place in `D2`